# Unable to remove text-decoration with 2nd span tag inside of TD tag

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for hours to find a way to remove a text decoration within a TD tag.  I've used SPAN CLASS to apply underline and a smaller font size to one portion of my text within a tables TD tag.  But when I try to remove it with textdecoration: none either via a CSS class or with SPAN STYLE, it does not work.  I tried searching and find some questions about nested SPAN tags, but I am not nesting in this case.  I am closing the first span tag before opening the new one.

Is there lack of support with using two SPAN tags inside of one element (in this case being the TD?)  or is there some other way to achieve this?

JSFiddle: `otzfsvy2`

```
WARNING CONTAINS CONTENT NSFW
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otzfsvy2/

Any help to help me understand why I can't do it this way and what way would work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `>` here: `<td height='40' width='10'`

Working code should be:

```css
.playlistArtist {
    font-style:italic;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: Black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.noDecoration {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.playlist {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: Black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class='playlist' width='455' id='queueList' border='1'>
<col width='40'/>
<col width='365'/>
<col width='40'/>
<tr id='plTrTag_0' bgcolor='FFFFFF'>
 <td class='playlist' width='40' height='40'>
  <img width='40' height='40' src='http://lh6.ggpht.com/2iOdoyv7t1GgYw5-dJz9Z0facGcvQmw7-I85xs8_qjyKqFe8AesES_fJfDD-_Hmm21lJQYcUoT4HyITVjt_W2P8'></img>
 </td>
 <td height='40' width='10'>
  <span class='playlistArtist'>Kid Rock</span>
  <br/><span style='text-decoration:none;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bawitdabaw</span>
 </td>
 <td class='playlist' align='right' width='70px' height='40px'>
  <span id='plEntryDur0'>[Dur]</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 </td>
</tr>
```